# Pass asset as string to CodeIgniter Carabiner library

Tags: php, codeigniter, carabiner

[Carabiner](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Carabiner) will only accept paths in it's `js()` and `css()` functions:

```
$this->load->library('carabiner');
$this->carabiner->js('some/file/in/script/dir');
$this->carabiner->css('some/file/in/style/dir');
$this->carabiner->display();
```

I'm looking to return some scripts and styles by setting the return flag in `$this->load->view()` and pass it off to Carabiner in some function like `js_string()`, for example...

```
$custom_js = $this->load->view("js_with_php_in_it", null, true);
$this->carabiner->js_string($custom_js);
```

I've actually already solved the problem in a convoluted way by creating a Carabiner method called `from_string($type, $str)` that takes either 'js', or 'css' as it's first parameter, and the string itself as the second:

```
function from_string($type, $str){
    //we'll name the file using this.
    $uniq = uniqid();
    //create a temporary file in the system's /tmp directory.
    $tmpAsset = tempnam("/tmp", $uniq);
    //Carabiner requires that your scripts are relative to $config['script_dir']
    //create a symbolic link in this directory because you can't pass it absolutes.
    $this->symbolicAsset = "assets/{$type}/{$uniq}";
    //open the file named with the unique ID in /tmp and set it up for writing.
    $handle = fopen($tmpAsset, "w");
    //write the script or style to this temporary file.
    fwrite($handle, $str);
    //point the symlink at it
    symlink($tmpAsset, $this->symbolicAsset);
    //pass this directory off to $this->carabiner->css() or $this->carabiner->js()
    $this->$type($uniq);
}
```

I then `unlink()` the temporary file in Carabiner's `__destruct()`... But, I quite hate this solution for obvious overhead reasons: I'm creating a temporary file containing the same contents as the original only because of Carabiner's strict asset directory rules. Has anybody modified Carabiner in the past to enable it to parse strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is good feature missing in this library, i have used this library in my major projects after seeing this question i made some modifications in library to accept javascripts and css styles as string or array of strings with groups it will not create temporary file it will create in pages script tag and styles here is how this library will work now.

**javascript strings**

```
// script passed as string
$this->carabiner->js_string('alert("test script")'); 

// script passed as array
$this->carabiner->js_string(array('alert("test script")','alert("test script")'); 

// script passed as string with group name
$this->carabiner->js_string('alert("test script")','group_name'); 

// script passed as array with group name
$this->carabiner->js_string(array('alert("test script")','alert("test script")','group_name'); 

//load javascript along with javascript files without group name
$this->carabiner->display('js');

//load javascript along with javascript files with group name
$this->carabiner->display('group_name');
```

**css style strings**

```
// style passed as string
$this->carabiner->css_string('p{background:red}'); 

// styles passed as array
$this->carabiner->css_string(array('p{background:red}','p{background:red}'); 

// style passed as string with group name
$this->carabiner->css_string('p{background:red}','css_group_name'); 

// style passed as array with group name
$this->carabiner->css_string(array('p{background:red}','p{background:red}','css_group_name'); 

//load style along with javascript files without group name
$this->carabiner->display('css');

//load styles along with javascript files with group name
$this->carabiner->display('css_group_name');
```

here is my git repo i just created and sent request for pull [Git Repo](https://github.com/umefarooq/Carabiner)

Comment: Congrats - You win! This is exactly what I wanted, thank you! Just plugged it into my application and it's working as expected. Cheers! *pays $150*

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but something to try:

I think if you hacked the _get_contents method to detect a .php file extension and if there is a php extension call `$this->CI->load->view('asset.php', true)` rather than `file_get_contents()` you might be partway there. From my perusing this would probably only work if you used minify or combine.